# How to vertically center the cursor in a UITextView

Tags: objective-c, textview

I try to vertically center my text cursor in a UITextView.

```
// creating the inputText
[inputTextView removeFromSuperview];
inputTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(searchIconsButton.frame) + 3 , 0, buttomView.frame.size.width * 0.78 , buttomView.frame.size.height *0.80)];
inputTextView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
inputTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.6;
inputTextView.center = CGPointMake(inputTextView.center.x, buttomView.frame.size.height / 2);
inputTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
[inputTextView.layer setCornerRadius:6];
[inputTextView setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; // set the cursor color to black
inputTextView.textAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

I try in last line to do UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter but it still do not work .

You can see that the cursor hides into the Textview.

[image]

There is a way to solve it?

Comment: looking at your image, I would say you should use UITextField instead of UITextView...

Comment: but I have to use only UITextView.

Comment: why textview and why not uitextfield?

Comment: Because I use to display icons and words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `textContainerInset` property of `UITextView`, available iOS 7.0 and later.

```
inputTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-2,0,0,0); // Move cursor up 2
```

Play around with the values until it fits your needs.

Comment: How I can use this in textFiled ? It has something similar ?

Comment: UITextField does not have the same property. I believe you would have to subclass UITextField to change the behavior, but I am not sure. Try checking out the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html)

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The solution above is perfect but for those who are using swift 3 I have translated to the following ad its working perfectly.

```
  override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 2);
    }
```

Overriding the UITextField ofcouse

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has already been answered but the answers didn't work for me.
I have managed to achieve the desired difference in caret positioning by overriding this method:

```
-(CGRect) caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position
{
    CGRect nativeRect = [super caretRectForPosition:position];
    NSLog(@"nativeRect x:%f y:%f w:%f h:%f ", nativeRect.origin.x, nativeRect.origin.y, nativeRect.size.width, nativeRect.size.height);

    // Here you can do something with the desired positioning and size (for examaple, I incremented y):
    return CGRectMake(nativeRect.origin.x, nativeRect.origin.y + 2, nativeRect.size.width, nativeRect.size.height);
}
```